# Can I operate on this data as if it follows the normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

I have a sample of data (covering most of the population ~95%) with the following stats:

```
N: 2054
Min: 0.0
Q1: 0.11363636363636365
Median: 0.1590909090909091
Q3: 0.21
Max: 0.8534999999999999
IQR: 0.09636363636363635
Lower Outlier: -0.030909090909090886 (using a distance of 1.5)
Upper Outlier: 0.3545454545454545 (using a distance of 1.5)
μ: 0.1619543211771645
σ: 0.09235408845389574
σ²: 0.00852927765415
Skewness: 3.3355837213985198
Kurtosis: 22.702402425314517

Without outliers
N: 2018
Min: 0.0
Q1: 0.11363636363636365
Median: 0.1590909090909091
Q3: 0.20270270270270266
Max: 0.33783783783783783
IQR: 0.08906633906633901
μ: 0.15382437242829725
σ: 0.06410064498945531
σ²: 0.00852927765415
Skewness: -0.12077534253930963
Kurtosis: -0.0853421315576317
```

Can I operate on it as if it is normally distributed?

This data represents the normalized prices (in cents/kW·min) of electric car charge points in Portugal. My objective is to use the Z-score of a charge point as an indication of how cheap/expensive it is, along side its percentile.

If the Z-score is not suited for this use case do you have any suggestion on which metric should I use?

PS: if it makes a diference these are the outliers (the number after the arrow is how many outliers with that value exist):

```
0.40909090909090906 -> 2
0.8378378378378378 -> 1
0.4 -> 1
0.472972972972973 -> 2
0.47727272727272724 -> 1
0.36363636363636365 -> 2
0.8534999999999999 -> 14
0.8108108108108106 -> 1
0.4054054054054053 -> 9
0.5405405405405405 -> 3
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use actual prices as an indication of how expensive something is?

Comment: Show a Q-Q plot it can be much more "visual" to see if it seems gaussian or not.

Comment: Prices have up to three possible components: a flat fee, price per minute and price per kWh. Directly comparing them is hard. The normalization (which currently is excluding the flat fee) is in an unwielding unit (cents/kW·min). If the normalized prices are in a normal I could divide them in buckets: 0-16 percentile would be the \$ bucket, 16-50 percentile would be the \$\$ bucket, etc. The percentile and z-score of a charge point could also be shown for more advanced/knowledgeable users.

Comment: Binning, computing Z-scores, and using percentiles are all forms of direct comparison anyway: they just obscure the actual prices!

Comment: @Lelouch add the plot (used this guide https://www.statology.org/q-q-plot-excel/)

Comment: @whuber I will always show the full price with all the components. I can also show the normalization. But in addition I would like something more easily parsed at a glance (like \$, \$\$, \$\$\$, etc, à lá what Google does for the prices of restaurants)

Answer (score 0):

You have data for almost all of the population, so you  don't really need to do statistical inference.

Outliers account for something like 1/3 or 1/4 of your data; it does not seem appropriate to give a summary that excludes outliers.

Your objective is not stated. I assume this project is intended to provide a guide for motorists with electric cars (or who might be considering buying them)?  If so, your
idea of showing `$`, `$$`, `$$$`, etc., seems useful. (I do not
see the point of providing z-scores based on part of the data.)

Comment: I don't understand how the outliers account for 1/3 or 1/4 of the data. Can you elaborate?
The objective is to help the electric car drivers to pick the cheapest charge point to use. The \$, \$$, etc is helpful to quickly assess the charge point price. The z-score allows for a fine tune comparison between close charge points, aka, in the same \$ group.

Comment: The 1/3 to 1/4 fraction of outliers had to be a guessed from your graphs because I couldn't be sure of specific numbers.  However, even a few percent may be too many. (Consumers are entitled to know that outlier prices do exist.) // How is it better to use a z-scale (which would have to be explained) rather than actual cents per kW min which is instantly transparent? For a descriptive display, there is no need for anything to be normal or transformed to normal. Just trying to imagine how to make your descriptive summary as readable as possible.

Comment: I wouldn't be hiding the outliers, they would get either the \$ group or the highest \$ group (maybe \$\$\$\$\$). The argument for cents per kW min instead of a z-scale completely convinced me.